# Android Live Streaming based on javaCV + FFMpeg crashes by adding red5 link

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, red5, javacv

The Android application code is from:
[Android Live Streaming courtesy of JavaCV and FFMPEG](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/)

It streams the live camera video from the device.

I follow one comment's instruction (Yoshio Numai), to use Red5 as the stream server.
By Red5 itself, I can successfully use simpleBroadcaster and simpleSubscriber to stream and display the live camera (from the computer) steam.

In the MainActivity.java, I change the code as below:

```
private String ffmpeg_link = "rtmp://192.168.1.105/oflaDemo/red5StreamDemo";
```

And I can start the app in my Android device (Nexus 4).
after click "start", the app crash, pops out a small window, saying:
"Unfortunately, JavaCV 0.3 Stream Test has stopped. OK."

Once I click the OK button, I find the app is still live in the task list.

But the same thing will happen. 
What's wrong here?

Comment: Hi, i am also working with this example its working well for me,can you post your log information then i can check.

Comment: @Giridharan, I didn't work on this topic anymore, right now hard to trace back. I guess maybe some bugs have been fixed?

Comment: No i didn't do much changes in coding,i just update android sdk version and i use wowza and Nginx server to get the stream